# compile error on array?

Tags: c, arrays

I declare at first the array:

```
int array[5] = {'5', '6'};
```

but it doesn't give any error and shuts down. what is the reason? am i doing wrong?I tried also this

```
int N = 5;
int array[N] = {'5', '6'};
```

Comment: What exactly is "it doesn't give any error and shuts down"? If it doesn't compile, there shall be some messages. Or it compiles but crashes while execution, please specify.

Comment: Also, `int array[5]={'5','6'};` shall be totally fine in `C`.

Comment: It sounds like your program is crashing. Build a debug version, and run in a debugger. It will stop when (and where) the crash happens.

Comment: `int array[5] = {'5', '6'};` will initialize the array with `'5'`, `'6'`, `0`, `0`, `0`. It's the same as `int array[5] = {'5', '6', 0, 0, 0};`.

Comment: Please provide the full program. What you are showing doesn't make clear in any way what you are doing.

Comment: Variable-length array is not possible to write an initializer like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you filling an array of ints with chars, and if you are using braces to create the array, you don't need to put a number in the square brackets.

Your code should be:

int array[] = {2,3};

Comment: 1. Nothing wrong with specifying the array size and not initializing all the elements. If one declares the value of some elements at the beginning of an array, the remaining elements will be implicitly initialized to 0. Maybe the OP wants that. 2. In C values between 2 `'`s are int constants (char in C++, but they can be promoted to int anyway)

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing your array of `int`s with `char`s. It should be

```
int arr[5] = {2,3};
```

it will initialize `arr[0]` to `2` and `arr[1]` to `3`. Rest of them initialized to `0`.
Now, [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) can't be initialized by using array initializer. You have to initialize it by assigning a valuse to its elements particularly. You can use a `for` loop as

```
int N = 5;
int arr[N];

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
```

Comment: Except that it ISN'T a variable-length array, and the original initializer worked perfectly fine (in fact, the question was why it didn't give an error).

Answer (score 0):

I use gcc on ubuntu, i declared `int array[5] = {'5', '6'};` and run with `gcc -Wall Labtest.c`, got response `warning: unused variable ‘array’ [-Wunused-variable]` which is what you should get. if you try to use the undeclared variables, the compile will initialize the value to zero. in my case i tried to print out the values of the array.

```
int array[5]={'5','6'};
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
printf("array[%d] is : %d\n", i, array[i]);
```

Output

```
array[0] is : 53
array[1] is : 54
array[2] is : 0
array[3] is : 0
array[4] is : 0
```